# Read/Write Data between multiple Android Apps

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-contentprovider

So I have a JSON file that was previously read and written using public external storage. As of API29, I have to transition so that when API 30 comes along (this summer), I can no longer used external storage as I have before. I've tried using `Content Providers`, but unfortunately, I am getting an error saying that multiple apps cannot have the same provider installed on the same device. Maybe I am misunderstanding it, but it looks like this path will not work. Is there any other publicly available storage on an android device that I can read/write a JSON file to? Btw, my multiple apps have variously formatted identifiers, from when I was a complete Android newbie. Didn't even own a domain, so I had somewhat random identifiers, so I can't take advantage of sharing data when apps have similar identifiers.

Any ideas?

Comment: I told you at your other post that you can continue what you did before 10 on 10 and 11 too.

Comment: `but unfortunately, I am getting an error saying that multiple apps cannot have the same provider installed on the same device` Of course not. You should give them different authorities. What is the problem?

Comment: Requestlegacy only works until this summer as we won't be able to target anything below api30 at that time.

Comment: Problem: I have 6 apps which should all share the same data (read/write). Users can install any mixture of them, so there's no parent app. They're all siblings. Looks like I might be able to do manage_external_storage, but it seems like this is a last ditch effort and may be not allowed by Google Play review since I'm only managing one data file.

Comment: Requesting legacy external storage works for Android 10 devices and works also targetting api 30. So keep on using it.

Comment: For Android 11+ You could use Storage Access Framework to write your file in for instance the Documents directory. Every app should at first run force the user to choose that Documents directory with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE.